# Android Studio 4.1.1 setup stuck at downloading

Tags: android, android-studio

My Android Studio 4.1.1 setup gets stuck at:

```
Preparing "Install Android Emulator (revision: 30.2.6)".
Downloading https://dl.google.com/android/repository/emulator-linux-6962233.zip
```

Acessing `https://dl.google.com/android/repository/emulator-linux-6962233.zip` on the browser works.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. Maybe it is a general problem.